# Can two or more breadcrumbs lead to the same end site?

Tags: seo, breadcrumbs

I have a question about breadcrumbs and SEO!

Currently my website's navigation is with the links above site where user can click desired category and continue with different filters.

On the next update we are planning to add site navigation on bottom of the site where some popular tags will be listed, and will lead to another page that will give most recent results in table, and will enable tags drill down... So basically this will be another way to browse data... The whole idea about building this is to make data more SEO friendly - That is why I want to add breadcrumbs here.

I am not sure if multiple breadcrumbs are allowed to lead to the same URL.

If they are allowed than I would like to ask for the solution for breadcrumbs on last site in chain... This should also have 2 because user can go back on one or another chain ...

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're thinking about this all wrong...

Firstly, forget SEO, think UX. Both breadcrumbs and tags (and any other additional navigable functionality) should be for the benefit of the website visitor, there is minimal SEO benefit in this sense because what you'll end up with is countless pages on your site competing for similar/the same terms causing [keyword cannibalisation](http://moz.com/blog/how-to-solve-keyword-cannibalization).

The purpose of a breadcrumb trail is to show the user the path to the current page they are viewing giving them the option to navigate a level up in the same way you would browse directories on an operating system GUI. Whilst there can be an element of weight in terms of SEO in the sense that these links will link to the pages with relevant anchors, there is often going to be multiple links to these pages (mainly in the form of primary navigation) so the SEO on these will be diminished. Read more about the [benefits of breadcrumbs trails](http://usabilitygeek.com/12-effective-guidelines-for-breadcrumb-usability-and-seo/).

I would never expect more than one path in a breadcrumb trail to direct to the same URL as this falls outside the above scope of what breadcrumbs are intended for but different pages can direct to the same URL's as part of the path to the current page, even with different anchors if this is more relevant to the path and current location of the visitor.

You could consider the possibility of implementing dropdowns in the breadrumb trails in the event there is more than one path to get to the same page but you need to consider the ease of use for the visitor. Over complicating usability elements of a website such as navigation, breadcrumbs and tags can quickly reduce the effect of them making them redundant for their intended purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ... But I found Google's idea of multiple breadcrumbs ON https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/185417?hl=en under Microdata at the end of the page... They give example of a book that can be found in: Books > Fiction > Horror 
OR 
Books > Authors > "author name"

Comment: Yes, I explained that in my answer...